How can MQTT subscriber receive AMQP message in RabbitMQ?
I published AMQP message to queue, and binding to amq.topic exchange with binding key #.
I can see the MQTT subscriber queue also binding to amq.topic exchange with binding key #.
While published message to AMQP queue, I can see it in AMQP queue, but MQTT queue do not receive the message.
Is there any problem with RabbitMQ configuration?


Change queue binding key, public message again, change MQTT client.
Expect advice to RabbitMQ configuration.
